# Thymeleaf: Template not accessible downloading a PDF online with Spring Boot 2.0.3

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

I'm downloading a PDF file with a web app, developed with Spring Boot 2.0.3 and using Thymeleaf, from an admin section, protected with Spring Security. **Locally it works fine, but online I get this error**:

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/email/confirmedbooking", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause`

This is the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/admin/bookings/booking-pdf")
public void generatePdfBooking(@RequestParam Long idbooking, HttpServletResponse response)
                               throws IOException, Exception{

    bookingService.setBookingService(idbooking);
    Booking booking = bookingService.getBooking();
    Guest guest = bookingService.getGuest();

    String idlanguage;
    if(guest.getIdlanguage() != null){
        idlanguage = guest.getIdlanguage();
    } else {idlanguage = "en";}

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("booking", booking);
    map.put("guest", guest);

    byte[] data = pdfGenerator.createPdf("/email/confirmedbooking", map, idlanguage);

    pdfGenerator.streamReport(response, data, "id-" + booking.getIdbooking() + ".pdf");
}
```

This is an extract of the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap /css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/rentalwebs.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <table style="width:680px" class="table table-borderless">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2 th:text="${property.name}"></h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span th:text="#{booking.id}"></span>
                    <span th:text="${booking.idbooking}"></span>
                    ....
```

As a template generator I'm using org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer (flying-saucer-pdf).

I've tested providing different .html files to generate the PDF at `pdfGenerator.createPdf("/email/confirmedbooking", map, idlanguage);`, but the result is always the same.

Comment: It seems to not like the path you've given, i.e. `"/email/confirmedbooking"`. Is it supposed to be a file system path or a class path reference? That path won't exist in the file system, as your app will be under `/home/vcap/app`. Aside from that, do you have a more complete demo that replicates the problem which you could share.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from Daniel Mikusa, I have been able to solve the issue, taking out the first  / from `/email/confirmedbooking`, leaving the code like this:

```
byte[] data = pdfGenerator.createPdf("email/confirmedbooking", map, idlanguage);
```

It seems that it didn't recognise the path, probably because of the double slash issue, already explained at this post: [Error resolving template with Spring Boot using Thymeleaf packaged in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400967/error-resolving-template-with-spring-boot-using-thymeleaf-packaged-in-a-jar/48501104#48501104)